# Merge requests never complete after gitlab omnibus 14.3.6

Tags: gitlab

I'm running the omnibus gitlab package 14.0.12. After updating >= 14.3.6, merge requests no longer work correctly.

The 'assignee', 'reviewer', and 'time tracking' panels in the right sidebar just spin indefinitely. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbjuu.jpg)

It works again when I revert back to 14.0.12.

I've been unable to find anything useful in the release notes, logs, or a packet capture.

Could anyone point me in some direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitlab was fine, my own browser was just too old.

I was using Firefox 70 and apparently it breaks some of the JS on gitlab. I had the same 'invalid regexp group' error in the console as in this issue:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/339482